# Postgresql, I cannot connect with the user

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL coming from the MySQL. I installed postgreSQL to my VPS. Then I created new user , I can see the user I created when I typed \du command. I want to try connect from local with this command: `psql -U backend -h localhost -p 5432`. Then asked me to prompt password. After I entered my password I get following error :
`psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "backend" does not exist`

I couldn't understand why postgresql give database not found error. How can I solve ? I also tried to connect from Goland, but getting same error. I am using PostgreSQL 16.

Comment: `psql` is a [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq.html) program so read [Keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) for what the program is expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

psql is by default trying to connect to database named the same as your user (-U option), so it's tryting to connect to db named **backend**. Try to either define your existing db by passing the -d option:

```
psql -U backend -h localhost -p 5432 -d your_database_name
```

or if you are not sure, list all databases to see which one you want to connect to:

```
psql -U backend -h localhost -p 5432 -l
```